# Get the name against data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Have data in below format

```
Code        Name
C-123456    XYS Contracting
31-Mar-17   CNC/SIV45678/CNC/SI-45678
21-Dec-17   CNC/SIV7894/CNC/SI-7894
21-Dec-17   CNC/SIV12348/CNC/SI-12348
31-May-18   CNC/SIV23458/CNC/SI-23458
31-May-18   CNC/SIV3456/CNC/SI-3456
30-Jun-18   CNC/SIV56789/CNC/SI-56789
30-Jun-18   CNC/SIV1346/CNC/SI-1346
14-Aug-18   CNC/FTIV00198/CNC/FTI00198
14-Aug-18   CNC/FTIV00199/CNC/FTI00199
31-Aug-18   CNC/SIV30964/CNC/SI-30964

Total due
```

and I need to data in the below format

```
Code        Name            Date        Invoice Number
C-123456    XYS Contracting 31-Mar-17   CNC/SIV45678/CNC/SI-45678
C-123456    XYS Contracting 21-Dec-17   CNC/SIV7894/CNC/SI-7894
C-123456    XYS Contracting 21-Dec-17   CNC/SIV12348/CNC/SI-12348
C-123456    XYS Contracting 31-May-18   CNC/SIV23458/CNC/SI-23458
C-123456    XYS Contracting 31-May-18   CNC/SIV3456/CNC/SI-3456
C-123456    XYS Contracting 30-Jun-18   CNC/SIV56789/CNC/SI-56789
C-123456    XYS Contracting 30-Jun-18   CNC/SIV1346/CNC/SI-1346
C-123456    XYS Contracting 14-Aug-18   CNC/FTIV00198/CNC/FTI00198
C-123456    XYS Contracting 14-Aug-18   CNC/FTIV00199/CNC/FTI00199
C-123456    XYS Contracting 31-Aug-18   CNC/SIV30964/CNC/SI-30964

        Total due
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Consider using markdown to format your data in your question.

Comment: I'm unable to understand that how you are expecting to get  records like the Output you are expecting since there is no relationship between Source and the Target data. Above all from where you are getting Date Invoice Number. Better share some sample data with us.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for AWK rather than an Excel question. You should deefinitely add more details about your input data and what you intend to do with the result. We don't even know how you want the output to look like since your question was formatted by someone else. You can use the following AWK, possibly tweaking it to match your unspecified needs:

```
/^$/ {
    print
    next
    }
/Total due/ {
    print "\t"$0
    next
    }
NR==2 {
    a=$1"\t"$2" "$3;
    print "Code\t\tName\t\t\tDate\t\tInvoice Number"
}
NR>2 {
    print a"\t\t"$1"\t"$2
    }
```

**How to use it:**

I assume the input is the contents of a file called `input.txt`. Save the script in a file called, e.g. `script.awk`, then run it with the command `awk -f script.awk input.txt`

**Output:**

```
Code            Name                    Date            Invoice Number
C-123456        XYS Contracting         31-Mar-17       CNC/SIV45678/CNC/SI-45678
C-123456        XYS Contracting         21-Dec-17       CNC/SIV7894/CNC/SI-7894
C-123456        XYS Contracting         21-Dec-17       CNC/SIV12348/CNC/SI-12348
C-123456        XYS Contracting         31-May-18       CNC/SIV23458/CNC/SI-23458
C-123456        XYS Contracting         31-May-18       CNC/SIV3456/CNC/SI-3456
C-123456        XYS Contracting         30-Jun-18       CNC/SIV56789/CNC/SI-56789
C-123456        XYS Contracting         30-Jun-18       CNC/SIV1346/CNC/SI-1346
C-123456        XYS Contracting         14-Aug-18       CNC/FTIV00198/CNC/FTI00198
C-123456        XYS Contracting         14-Aug-18       CNC/FTIV00199/CNC/FTI00199
C-123456        XYS Contracting         31-Aug-18       CNC/SIV30964/CNC/SI-30964

        Total due
```

**Note:**

This is possibly *not* what you want. Please add more details and change e.g. the number of tabs in the output.

Comment: You say: *You should deefinitely add more details ...* , *We don't even know ...* and *This is possibly not what you want.*. So why do you answer a question with so many uncertainties? Why don't you ask (in a comment to the question) the OP to provide more details, instead. What value do you think this question/answer has for future readers?

Comment: @TomBrunberg My post has the double goal of *answering the question as it is*, and *providing a starting point* that should be easy to understand and tweak to fulfill *slightly* different needs. I second the existing comment to the question and I upvoted it. I suspect the OP *might* want CSV output ignoring the lines not containing data, and I *expect* readers to be able and willing to achieve that by fiddling just a little with the provided code.

Comment: @simlev, if the code you have shown is possible to execute in Excel then just edit the post and add the steps to achieve the goal !!

Comment: @RajeshS Let me repeat that this looks like a job for AWK. You could of course do the same with VBA, but I don't see the point, given that input and output do not appear to be Excel files.

Comment: @simlev, OP is looking for the solution which is within the reach of Excel (may possible with VBA) but not  the C or C++ Coding. Please edit the post  and if possible replace  the code with VBA to make in more relevant, otherwise this may attract Negative vote !!

Comment: @RajeshS We don't know for sure what the OP is looking for, let's wait until more details are added. Thank you heartily for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Power Query, please follow my steps:

You can remove Code and Name row, then select the range- Go to Data- From Table/Range.

In Power Query Editor select C-123456 Column and go to Transform- select Unpivot Column. Then same steps for XYS Contracting Column.

Please refer to this .gif:

[image]